# Error while start openerp

Tags: postgresql, odoo

i have installed openerp. i have created postgres database. While i open ¨localhost:8060¨ in browser, display the followin error:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 761, in get_list
    monodb = db_monodb(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 129, in db_monodb
    return db_redirect(req, True)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 109, in db_redirect
    dbs = db_list(req, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 90, in db_list
    dbs = proxy.list(force)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 122, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 359, in exp_list
    cr = db.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 484, in cursor
    return Cursor(self._pool, self.dbname, serialized=serialized)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 182, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn(dbname))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 377, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/sql_db.py", line 440, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: FATAL:  role "bala" does not exist
```

otherwise i started like following ¨openerp-server start¨, error following like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('openerp==7.0-20140110-002122', 'openerp-server')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 499, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1235, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 51, in main
    __import__(m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/l10n_si/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import account_wizard
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp-7.0_20140110_002122-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/l10n_si/account_wizard.py", line 22, in <module>
    import tools
ImportError: No module named tools
```

Anyone help for error correction. i cannot clear this error even two days i spend for this.

Comment: then how to start openerp?

Comment: how you start server and where is your openerp-server path?

Comment: @MarianTheisen A more constructive comment - or at least one that tells the rest of us what not to do - would be nice.

Comment: @CraigRinger, you're right. i just had another few days of fixing openerp bugs behind me ;).

Comment: @user3145948, if you're just starting with openerp, consider alternatives. if you're already deciced on openerp, i maybe can give you some tips.

Answer (score 0):

> OperationalError: FATAL:  role "bala" does not exist

A user that you have told OpenERP to use does not exist in the database. You probably need to create it. I expect you missed one or more installation steps.

Look for a `CREATE USER`, `CREATE ROLE`, or `createuser` command in the instructions.

`GRANT` commands or a database ownership assignment may also be nececssary depending on what the user is supposed to be able to do.

(It might also be assumed that you'll know to create the user to connect to the DB as).